# Codeigniter - Is there a way to access the data in the object from $this->db->get_where() directly?

Tags: codeigniter

I am just curious if there a way to access the data in the object from $this->db->get_where() directly without resorting to result_object(), result_array(), row_array(), row_object(), etc.

Even so, does this break good OOP practice  of encapsulating objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use it via:

```
$result = $this->db->get_where()->result();
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

[Select data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) and [Generating query result](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) posts might help you.

Comment: That works for getting the values but I was interested in accessing the data directly for the purposes of changing it by reference inside the object.

Comment: Encapsulation is nothing but defining variable's scope by defining access specifiers, so no, it does not break anything.

Also, $this->db->get_where() returns an object, you cannot directly throughput data string or data array from an object. Anything that you do requires right 'return' defined :)